# Data binding in class name in angular 2

Tags: angular

I want to do data-binding with html classname in angular2 like this.

```
<label [className]={{classname}} >
```

where classname is @Input. 
I am passing classname from another component while calling this component in following manner.

```
<app-file-uploader [classname]="'uploader0'" [label]="'DRAG & DROP YOUR SIGNATURE'"></app-file-uploader>
```

But it is not working. It is giving some parse error. How can I achieve it?

Comment: did it solve your issue

Comment: yess!! I was just using wrong syntax

Comment: mark as answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to put the **`expression`**, try

```
<label [className]="classname">
```